# WordPress contact form rich text editor

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

Hey guys I am making custom pages in WP using PHP.

I don't have much experience with WordPress plugins so don't know how to attach rich text editor in my own form textarea field.

I was going through some rich text editors like wysihtml5, do you guys know how can I use these jQuery plugins with my textarea field so that I can give user the experience of text editing also save the data in a text field so later on when I fetch I can replicate the same thing.

Doing this manually is easy but in WordPress its new for me.

-Thanks

Comment: You actually wish to add richtext to Your frond end form ?

Comment: This function `wp_editor` will be work for You. Refer -- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

Comment: Will try this out and let you know.

Comment: It is not working properly... I think it's because of the custom page I have built so its not styling properly.

Comment: What is not working properly ? Get me more info.

Comment: The text editor is appending out of all the containers.

Comment: Edit Yor question and paste Your page code.

Comment: Sorry can't do that as its confidential. I found a solution, used CK Editor and it worked like a charm I took the lib from CND. Its not a                                                           "Proper Solution" but its working.This is the lib I included at the end [link](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.3/standard/ckeditor.js)

Comment: Great! Enjoy coding!